# Different versions of yocto in one project

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, ros

For a project I must use sumo, as it is the last version the vendor supports. However I also would like to use a layer containig ROS () which has the following compatibility:
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_ros-layer = "rocko sumo thud warrior"

But in the README.md it says that requires:

```
## DEPENDENCIES ##



This layer depends on:

  **openembedded-core**
  URI: git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
  subdirectory: meta
  branch: thud
  revision: HEAD

  **meta-openembedded (meta-oe)**
  URI: git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
  subdirectory: meta-oe
  branch: thud
  revision: HEAD

  **meta-python** (since a6d7ba92645a112af358efd94ff3aa0c74985a51@meta-openembedded)
  URI: git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
  subdirectory: meta-python
  branch: thud
  revision: HEAD

  **meta-multimedia** (since fe44ac167a2a76531af3519f3889fce92024567b@meta-openembedded)
  URI: git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
  subdirectory: meta-multimedia
  branch: thud
  revision: HEAD
```

When I use all layers with sumo, the ROS layer is not enabled:

ERROR: Layer 'escape' depends on layer 'ros', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration

Although I have it enabled:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ##OEROOT##/meta \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-poky \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-intel \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-aaeonc \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-ros \
  ##OEROOT##/meta-escape \
  "
```

So I guess it is a matter of dependencies (meta-escape is my layer and is the one taht requires ROS). But if I use thud, bitbake starts failing.

Is there a way to use two different versions of the same layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and straight: nope. You have to make sure the layers are compatible version-wise. Thats the whole point of the `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT` variable.

If a layer doesn't happen to be available for the release you want, you can always change the entry and try, but might run into breakage.

Good luck.